# Key input functions for a VB class file

Tags: vb.net, function, input

I am working on a little framework and I want to have a class file that contains functions I can run to check if a certain key has been pressed so other events can be run. The only code I have found online for similar things are written into the form itself and use something like "Handles Me.KeyPress". However, this handle function can't be used in a class file.

```
Public Function OnKeyPress(KeyToCheck As Keys)

        If KeyPressed = KeyToCheck then
             return true
        else
             return false
        End If

    End Function
```

I have tried:

```
       Public Function OnKeyPress(KeyToCheck As Keys)Handles Formname.Keypress

        If KeyPressed = KeyToCheck then
             return true
        else
             return false
        End If

    End Function
```

However, this does not work. Any suggestions or work arounds would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This [LINK](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/creatingEvents.htm) might help ;)

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to follow the article but I get the error
_Method 'Public Function OnKeyPress(Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Object' cannot handle event 'Public Event TimesUp()' because they do not have a compatible signature._
and I am not sure what is causing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get keyboard input, you need to have a window. All input goes to a window, and that window can then check for key presses that are sent to it.

To get global information, you'd need to install a hook, but those should generally be avoided.

Comment: Thanks :D I will see if I can use forms to get a work around. :)